Search and Filter opened PopMenuButton
Is there any way that the list filtering triggers a rebuild/update of the opened PopUpMenuButton when I search in the textfield? The pseudo code below only works when I reopen the PopUpMenuButton. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is showing only PopMenuItems based on the filtered list that is typed in the textfield that is the first PopMenuItem
Initialization of the TextEditing Controller
    @override
      void initState() {
        _searchFilterController = TextEditingController()..addListener(_searchFilterListener);
        items = ['Item 1', 'Sample 2', 'Selection 3'];
       }

Search function
void _searchFilterListener() {
    final query = _searchFilterController.text;

    
        final filteredItems = items.where((item) =>
                query.isNotNullOrBlank ? filteredItems.contains(query) == true : true)
            .toList();

        setState(() {
          items = filteredItems;
        });
      },
    );
      }

Widget Sample
          PopupMenuButton<T>(
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem<String>(
                child: TextField(
                controller: _searchFilterController,
                 ),
                ),
              ),
              ...items.map(
                (item) => PopupMenuItem<T>(
                  child:  Text(item)
                  ),
                 ),
            ],
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(child: Text('')),
                    Chevron.down(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),


Use SearchBar widget instead.
Link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchBar-class.html
